# Unable to connect to published Docker port on OS X

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run a simple Node.js/Express web app in a Docker (17.06) container on OS X (latest update 10.12.5). I'm unable to connect to the app at `localhost:3000` and am unable to figure out what's wrong. I have also tried to connect to the VM's IP address found by running `ip addr | grep global` in its console to no avail.

My app is actually just the framework JetBrains Webstorm creates when creating a new project of type 'Node.js Express App'. Note that I'm able to run this app on my host system via `npm start` and successfully connect to it at `localhost:3000`.

I then built a Docker image like so:

```
docker build -t joonas/meancopy .
```

Run it:

```
docker run -it -v `pwd`:/home/dev/src --name meancopy joonas/meancopy -p 3000:3000
```

And after being thrown in the VM's shell, I run `npm start` and get the following:

```
[dev@c24d24f58f1d:~/src$ npm start
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@5.0.3
npm info using node@v8.1.2
npm info lifecycle npmtest@0.0.0~prestart: npmtest@0.0.0
npm info lifecycle npmtest@0.0.0~start: npmtest@0.0.0

> npmtest@0.0.0 start /home/dev/src
> node ./bin/www
```

The output is the same as when run on the host expect for the "npm info" lines in the beginning. However, I'm unable to connect to this server at `localhost:3000`.

I've also tried running the image with `--expose=3000` and `--net="host"` because I found those when searching for solutions online, but they don't help (and to my understanding shouldn't even be necessary here).

Any help or debugging ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `docker run` command is bad

```
docker run -it -v `pwd`:/home/dev/src --name meancopy joonas/meancopy -p 3000:3000
```

the way you have this written, the container is going to try and execute `-p 3000:3000` as the container's process instance. you need to put the `-p` parameter *before* the the name of the image.

```
docker run -it -v `pwd`:/home/dev/src --name meancopy -p 3000:3000 joonas/meancopy
```

Now docker will run the command defined in your Dockerfile - which will probably be the node.js app, as expected.